# How to include json content inside a js variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have this js variable which is parsing a json content inline:

```
var places = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "theatre"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
        }
    }]
};
```

I need this content to be inside an external json file since it is a long list to load dynamically.

Can you tell me how to call the json file (the code must be as it is and not parsed)? I tried dozens of solution here but without results :(

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: is this frontend or backend (Node.js)?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Put the JSON (just the part between `{ }`) in a file and use `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, use `fetch()`, `Response()`, and `json()` methods.

Comment: Or use `XMLHttpRequest` and `JSON.parse()` in the callback function.

Comment: Maybe you can just put it in a .js file and link the js file in the header.

Comment: just put your code (including the variable declaration) in another .js file and add it as a seperate script to your page, with another script tag, and put that script above the script that needs it... then you can just access the data thru the `places` variable as if it were in the same script.

Comment: Last solution works just fine: Thanks a lot!